# Making a reliable and stable locationing service with scheduling

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-alarms, android-wake-lock

**The feature I would like to achieve:**

At a certain date a service should start that is getting location information and pushing it to the server. At a certain date the service should stop.

1. The starting and ending time is very important to be accurate.
2. The service should be reliable as much as it can, OS should not kill it.
3. Service starting and ending must be automatic, without user interaction.

**Here is what I achieved:**

1. I have a database in my application that is holding "schedulings". Start time, end time.
2. I have a ServiceScheduler class that is reads the schedulings from DB and set alarms with AlarmManager to the specific dates, using PendingIntents, and WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
3. WakefulBroadcastReceiver actually starts the service, and i got another BroadcastReceiver for stopping it.
4. My Service is a simple service, so NOT an IntentService, i use it in startForeground mode.

**What i have learned in the process while tried to make the feature reliable and usable as it should be:**

1. My ServiceScheduler should re-set the alarms after device is rebooted, because alarms are being cleared on turning off.
2. Starting foreground mode is a great way to minimalize the chance that OS will kill the service.
3. Starting the service with WakefullBroadcastReceiver instead of simple BroadcastReceiver is a must be to ensure that device will wake up from sleep mode.

**Tests:**

1. The service is not yet 100% reliable, and I suspect that sleep mode is in the root of the problem.

**My questions:**

1. Is the device's sleeping mode prevents the service from well functioning? - Meaning of getting location information with "fused location", caching locations to a DB and pushing some data to server.
2. Is it possible that after the service starts, the device could go back to sleep mode?
3. If i choose to keep the device awake the whole interval while the service is running, is it a good practice to acquire a wakelock at service's onCreate and release it on onDestroy?

**My simplified code:**

```
    public class ServiceScheduler
    {

    //Class for scheduling a service from a scheduling instance (read from DB)

    //.. much simple version just to explain

        private void schedule(Scheduling scheduling){

            //Intent for the ServiceStartBroadcastReceiver
            Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), ServiceStartBroadcastReceiver.class);

            //pending intent for the alarmManager
            PendingIntent startPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx.getApplicationContext(), 0, startServiceIntent, 0);

            //setting alarm to start the service at the specific time
//setExact's required API level is too high for the project
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduling.startTime.getTime(), startPendingIntent);


            //Intent for the ServiceStopBroadcastReceiver
            Intent endServiceIntent = new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), ServiceStopBroadcastReceiver.class);

            //pending intent for the alarmManager
            PendingIntent endPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx.getApplicationContext(), 0, endServiceIntent, 0);

            //setting alarm to stop the service at the specific time
//setExact's required API level is too high for the project
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduling.endTime.getTime(),endPendingIntent);
        }

    }


    public class ServiceStartBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    //BroadcastReceiver to start the service

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, GpsService.class);

            //start in wakeful mode
            startWakefulService(context, startServiceIntent);

        }
    }


    public class ServiceStopBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    //BroadcastReceiver to stop the service

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


            //Stopping the service
            Intent stopServiceIntent = new Intent(context, GpsService.class);
            context.stopService(stopServiceIntent);

        }

    }


    public class GpsService extends Service {

      //Using wake lock, is it necessary?
        private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;


        @Override
        public void onCreate() {

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "locationServiceWakeLock");


        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


              //Wake lock !? is it necessary?
            if (!wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                wakeLock.acquire();
            }


            //completing the wakefull intent which is started at ServiceStartBroadcastReceiver
            ServiceStartBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);


            //Which mode should i use and why as return?
            return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }



        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {


           //Wake lock !? is it necessary?
            wakeLock.release();


        }



    }
```

**Please tell me all your advices**

I've been making this now for a long time and the solution is close. I have read all the articles and documentation i found but iam still uncertain at some things.

Comment: Nicely asked - I have done something of that sort - but I did not use WBR I used WakefulIntentService instead. maybe therein lies the difference ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I checked the source code and the main difference is that commonsware using IntentService but he is using wakelock, maybe i should too.

Comment: The WBR should be using a wake lock too - the two approaches are equivalent IIUC - you may be not using the WBR wakelock correctly